# java - how to limit operation(e.g login) by cowndown timer

Tags: java, timer

i need some help in my login GUI form (created with `javax.swing`), basically i want to (kind of block) a user from login at 10 failure attempt for amount of time, it starts with 5 seconds, every thing fine first time, but when attempt reaches >10 i want to increase waiting time, how to make amount of time is increase 5 more seconds?, more clearly i want to do this

> 10 failure attempt, login form is disabled, you have to wait 5 seconds! then try again
>
> 11 failure attempt, login form is disabled, you have to wait 10 seconds! then try again
>
> .
>
> .

i tried a `javax.swing.Timer` for this:

```
else if(ATTEMPT>10)
    {
        System.out.println("attempt is more than 10");
        try
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you can wait for now", "10 attemtp", 1);
            this.setEnabled(false);
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    System.out.println("timer started");
                    SECONDS--;                           //SECONDS is an integer =5 in class
                    jLabel6.setText("you can try again in "+SECONDS);
                    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
                    if(SECONDS==0)
                    {
                        setEnabled(true);
                        login_btn.setEnabled(true);
                        ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                        System.out.println("timer has stopped");
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but i didn't figured out a way to increase waiting time.

this will work perfect for first time, but how can i increase time by 5s for another failure attempt? is using `timer` is the best solution in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually hardcode `SECONDS` to `5` according to your comment :

> ```
> SECONDS--;   //SECONDS is an integer =5 in class
> ```

So the waiting delay is 5 seconds (1000 from the timer * 5 = 5000 ms).
What you want is  a variable time that depends on the number of attempt, that is : `SECONDS = 5 * (ATTEMPT - 9);`

- SECONDS = 5 * 1 = 5 for the 10th attempt
- SECONDS = 5 * 2 = 10 for the 11th attempt

And so for...

Which gives :

```
else if(ATTEMPT>10)
    {
        SECONDS = 5 * (ATTEMPT - 9);` // CHANGE HERE
        System.out.println("attempt is more than 10");
        try
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you can wait for now", "10 attemtp", 1);
            this.setEnabled(false);
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    System.out.println("timer started");
                    SECONDS--;                           //SECONDS is an integer =5 in class
                    jLabel6.setText("you can try again in "+SECONDS);
                    jLabel6.setVisible(true);
                    if(SECONDS==0)
                    {
                        setEnabled(true);
                        login_btn.setEnabled(true);
                        ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
                        System.out.println("timer has stopped");
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: wow, it works perfect, =) maybe it's just one line of code but it will take some time to me to grasp it, Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are very welcome.I am glad to hear that. You are a student : each thing has its time :) Good continuation :)